Discrete Fourier transform for time series with small time-shift measurements
I have a time series that can only take positive integer values in the range [0, 100]. This time series shows periodically recurring patterns which can be uncovered by using the discrete Fourier transform. However, there can be a small and bounded time shift in how the integer values are distributed over time.
For example, say that we have a true repeating pattern such as [0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100]. Due to practical measurement delays, however, the time series actually recorded could be [10, 90, 5, 95, 20, 80, 2, 98].
This time shift effect is different than additive white noise. For a window of reasonable size (say 10 entries), the sums of entries for the true and measured time series are guaranteed to be the same. So, if the measured time series has a value greater than the true time series at time step t, the next time steps t+1, t+2,... are guaranteed to have lower values to compensate for the increase at time t. And vice versa.
Is there a way to effectively handle such bounded 'time shift' noise? While the FFT approach is generally reliable, it occasionally generates numerous additional frequencies due to the measurement effects I've described. I suspect I'm not the first to encounter this issue.

Rather than white noise, you have biased noise. Sometimes you can use what you know about bias to adjust for it specially, but more generally, you handle it the same way as you would handle the white noise: once the magnitude of the frequencies drop below a certain threshold, you discard them.

Are you saying that you have unknown sample times so that what is sampled is not $f(t)$ but rather $f(t-\epsilon(t))$? But that $\int_{T}{f(t)\mathrm{d}t} = \int_{T}{f(t-\epsilon(t))\mathrm{d}t}$ as long as $T$ is less than some known value?
